# TypeError in Python

Tags: python

I have two classes for in case:

testing.py :

```
class Functions:
    def mapping(func, x):
        return func(x)
```

and I try to run the code below:

```
import testing

def doubleMe(data):
    return data * data

res = stream.Functions.map(testdouble, [1,2,3,4,5])
print res
```

After I try to run the code, I got the error

> TypeError: unbound method mapping() must be called with Functions
>   instance as first argument (got function instance instead)

I not too sure what what have went wrong here, can I have some advise? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Python functions always take the class or instance as the first argument of class functions/methods.

```
class Functions:
    def mapping(self, func, x):
        return func(x)
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to always create instances of the class, do the following to create a class method as opposed to an instance method.

```
class Functions:
    @classmethod
    def mapping(cls, func, x):
        return func(x)
```

The `@` operator creates a *function decorator*, if it's a topic you'd like to google more.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make much sense of your code (it seems incomplete, and names don't match up: mapping -> map, stream -> testing), but from the error message, it seems like you need to construct an instance of Function first.  So you need something like:

```
func = stream.Functions()
func.map(testdouble, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

You also need to declare the map/mapping method properly (after deciding whether you want an instance or class method), as Kurt pointed out.